# How I can delete all ObjectId in database (mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have testDB in MongoDB. And five collections.
I delete User by Id ObjectId("111") from collection "Users" but in collection "Clubs" Id's remained in field "members".
Can I delete IDs anywhere in Database?

Comment: Can you include the sample document from "Clubs" collection?

Comment: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57583d7ac9be6ade7d4281ca"),
    "name" : "Mimosa",
    "_creator" : ObjectId("57583164c9be6ade7d4281c7"),
    "subdomain" : "",
    "members" : [ 
        ObjectId("57580c4b203636137dbff0c9"), 
        ObjectId("57580caa203636137dbff0ca")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query to remove the user ids from "clubs" collection (i.e. members array).

Please note that the following query will delete the user ids from all the documents where members array contain the particular object id (i.e. user id). In other words, multiple documents will be updated.

If you need to limit the update for any specific condition, please include your condition in the first parenthesis which is left empty in the below query ('{}').

```
db.clubs.update({},
    {$pull: { members: { $in: [ ObjectId("57580c4b203636137dbff0c9")] }}},
    { multi: true });
```

Comment: Do i have utilities (commands) for delete all IDs in all collections?       
  when l delete root ID then i must delete IDs manually?      Why they not deleted automatically? This is logically if root ObjectId deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the example above

Comment: You have to delete it manually. Like relational database, there is NO cascade delete or referential constraints available in MongoDB. Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Thank you! The best, quick and complete answer.